# how to send data to api using vuejs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

i have a api call like below :

```
 this.$http.post("{{ route('shop.checkout.save-order') }}", {'_token': "{{ csrf_token() }}"})
                                .then(function (response) {
                                    if (response.data.success) {
                                        if (response.data.redirect_url) {
                                            window.location.href = response.data.redirect_url;
                                        } else {
                                            window.location.href = "{{ route('shop.checkout.success') }}";
                                        }
                                    }
                                })
```

now what i want to do is  taht i want to create an input like below :

```
<input type="text" name="delivery_time"  value="insert delivery time">
```

and add the value of the input and send it to api and get it from the `request()`helper in laravel
what i have tried so far is :

```
let formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("delivery_time"));
this.$http.post("{{ route('shop.checkout.save-order') }}", {'test':formData,'_token': "{{ csrf_token() }}"})
```

but this wont send the data to the api . thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add **v-model** in your input tag and assign an dynamic variable like below.

```
<input type="text" name="delivery_time"  value="insert delivery time" v-model="<deliveryTime>">
```

***V-model*** directive works as two way data binding hence whenever you will do any changes in input tag, it will get automatically reflected in variable . This value can be retrieved in your js part of component.

So you just need to pass that value, on the click of submit button.

```
this.$http.$post(url, {
    deliveryTime: deliveryTime
}, {
    // Config part( like authtoken
})
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't have any idea for  you way that you are doing.
You can use vue router + axios to handle your authentication.

Let read this to get more idea: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/10/authentication-in-vue-js/